# How to use Pandas to display specific columns from csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have a csv file with a number of columns in it. It is for students. I want to display only male students and their names. I used 1 for male students and 0 for female students. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('normalizedDataset.csv')

results = pd.concat([data['name'], ['students']==1])

print results
```

I have got this error:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

Can anyone help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify to read only certain column names of your data when you load your csv.  Then use `loc` to locate all values where `students` equals 1.

```
data = pd.read_csv('normalizedDataset.csv', usecols=['name', 'students'])
data = data.loc[data.students == 1, :]
```

BTW, your original error is because you are trying to concatenate a dataframe with False.

```
>>> ['students']==1
False
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to concat, you're stripping things away, not building.

Try:

```
data[data['friends']==1]['name']
```

Comment: You're performing chained indexing, I suggest `data.loc[data['friends']==1,'name']` to be semantically correct so the OP is operating on a view and not a copy

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Now, it looks better, but when I want to print them in a txt file in the directory, it gives an error. the rest of the code is:            fileHandle = open('facebookFriends.txt', 'w')
fileHandle.write("Facebook Friends \n")
for i in (results):
    outString = str(results[i]) + '  ' 
    fileHandle.write(outString)
fileHandle.close()

Comment: Thanks EdChum. Yes, I tried your code segment, and it gives me the results I need. However, I think it doesn't pass an int to a df to be printed in a txt file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

To provide clarity on why you were getting the error:

The second thing you were trying to concat was:

```
['students']==1
```

Which is not an `NDFrame` object.  You'd want to replace that with.

```
data[data['students']==1]['students']
```

Comment: Thanks piRSquared. How about the name of the student, how can I display it please?